# I'd like some help with something

Tags: video

I'm working on a YouTube video based on a Radio Play called, "The Hitchhiker". I asked David Von Penn to use his video for my plans. [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_vGz_Jbn54)

Again, I asked him permission, and he said yes. Unfortunately, I can't get it on YouTube Video Editor. It only has creative commons, but the video is of standard YouTube license. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube does not offer a simple way to do this.

Your two options are:

- download the video yourself using one of the numerous 3rd party tools for downloading YouTube videos
- get the original from the owner